# Is any class object serializable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'd like to store stuff in redux store, and want to know which one is serializable and which one is not.

1. class MyClass {
   }
2. var myClass = new MyClass

Specifically, are #1, #2 serializable?
What's the test/definition of serializability? 
Whether JSON.stringify() works without error?

https://github.com/markerikson/redux/blob/create-faq-page/docs/FAQ.md

**Can I put functions, promises, or other non-serializable items in my store state?**

It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you want to check if something is serializable, check if object == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));

Here's a few examples I ran in my browser window:

```
3 == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(3))
true
"foo" == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("foo"))
true
class MyClass {}
undefined
MyClass == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass))
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data [Learn More]
```

and in this case it apears that classes can't be serialized at all, since JavaScript just returned undefined.

Comment: This does not work: `{a: 1}` is serializable, but it will not be `==` (since `==` for objects checks referential identity, not equality). You can use one of [these methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) to test for deep equality.

Comment: Good point, my code only works with primitives. The idea is the same though, if the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) output is the same then it's serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Methods and functions (and any executable code snippets) can't be serialized, because you can't rehydrate them back wothout using `eval`.